# How do I install Ethernet drivers without internet

Tags: networking, drivers, internet, ethernet

I'm trying to revive an older PC as a Linux Server for games and Media storage. I Installed Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS Desktop Version but I can't get my Ethernet connection to work.
I spent the last couple hours looking through old forum posts but I keep hitting dead ends because I can't update anything on my machine without internet access and when I looked for the Linux drivers for my Intel Ethernet controller it said on their website that it is included in the kernel by now.

When I check with `lshw -c network` it says that the network is unclaimed and my Device is a Intel Ethernet controller 82579V

Edit:
Thanks for the Tip with the USB Tethering, makes it much easier to post info from the terminal.
I did  `sudo modprobe e1000e && sudo dmesg | grep e100` and got

```
[    0.621997] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver
[    0.621999] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2015 Intel Corporation.
[    0.622176] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode
[    1.564947] e1000e: probe of 0000:00:19.0 failed with error -2
```

Comment: Have you tried using Android/IOS device as network provider through USB connection?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `sudo modprobe e1000e && sudo dmesg | grep e100` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Does the computer BIOS/EFI have a setting to disable Wake-On-Lan? Please disable it and see if the dmesg error disappears. Reference: https://www.whtop.com/blog/e1000e-probe-failed-with-error-2/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This is a question answer site. I am happy that you solved your problem. You are most welcome to answer your own question. Please do not put the answer inside the question. Use the **Answer Your Own Question** button below to write the answer.

Answer (score 1):

***[SOLVED]***

I resolved the issue as followed:

I did a new install of ubuntu just to start over fresh.
This did not solve it.

When looking in my BIOS for the Wake-on-Lan and ACPI settings, I noticed that I might not have the latest BIOS version. I did some digging because Intel stopped providing a download for BIOS versions for this board. And found a newer version

***I updated the BIOS, changed Wake-on-Lan and ACPI settings to disabled*** and now the ethernet controller is recognized and working.

Thanks for the help :) I'm looking forward to get into linux now